# Java get specific element from Object[]

Tags: java, arrays

How can I print the second element from the below `Object[] args`? Is there a way to get it using `Arrays.toString(args)`. I want to get only the 2nd element `sayHello`

```
[com.example:type=Hello, sayHello, [Ljava.lang.Object;@1503f191, [Ljava.lang.String;@6229b4c0]
```

Comment: ***args[1]*** is going to do that... java arrays are zero indexed

Comment: `System.out.println(args[1].toString());` or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are objects that can be manipulated by indices too, those indices are integers pointing to its location in the object, furthermore, they are zero based, which means, the 1st element is located at index 0

[image]

following the illustration above, what you need is to do `Object foo = args[1];`

or invoke directly a method if required, e.g. `args[1].toString();`